# relative layout margin not working?

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to set the margin to the relative layout, but its not working, wondering why?
here is the layout containing listview,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="10dip">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"/>
```

and here is the view i want to inflate in that list view,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/subcat_list_selector" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/categoryIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<!-- Rightend Arrow -->

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/right_nav" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/categoryTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/categoryIcon"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/my_string"
    android:textColor="#999999"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a child relative layout inside the main layout with margin

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/subcat_list_selector" >

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/categoryIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<!-- Rightend Arrow -->

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/right_nav" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/categoryTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/categoryIcon"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/my_string"
    android:textColor="#999999"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

But this gives you a warning that the child layout is useless.